# How to get Application Insights TelemetryClient in Isolated .NET 7 Azure function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I create an Azure Function from the newest Visual Studio template and deploy it to Azure. I have setup Application Insights in the Azure portal so the actual code doesn't yet know about AppInsights. So far everything works.

Now I want to log some custom telemetry. What do I need to do?

I've tried the following:

- Taking a dependency on `TelemetryClient`

  - DI cannot resolve it
- Taking a dependency on `TelemetryConfiguration`

  - DI cannot resolve it
- Taking a dependency on `IOptions<TelemetryConfiguration>` and creating `TelemetryClient` from `options.Value`

  - Nothing happens. I guess just having the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` key in configuration is not enough

What to do?

Comment: [Have you read the very simple documentation on how to make this work?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Insights, with automatic dependency collection and correlation between application calling each other, can be used by adding the following package to the Azure Function.No other AppInsights related packages are needed to be installed.

> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights 1.0.0-preview4

and adding having the following program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

var host = new HostBuilder()
  .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((_, builder) =>
  {
      builder
          .AddApplicationInsights()
          .AddApplicationInsightsLogger();
  })
  .Build();

host.Run();
```

Then TelemetryClient can be used though DI and all "normal" data will be collected out of the box.

Note that the package is still in preview.

Comment: This answer does not work for the final version of the package. See the docs for usage here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#application-insights

Answer (score 3):

> How to get Application Insights TelemetryClient in Isolated .NET 7 Azure function?

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.35" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "308f2xxxxx039"
  }
}
```

**Function.cs:**

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;

namespace FunctionApp23
{
    public class Function1
    {
        public readonly TelemetryClient _tc;
        

        public Function1(TelemetryClient telClient)
        {
            _tc = telClient;
            
        }
        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, ILogger log)
        {
            _tc.TrackEvent("Function is running Rithwik");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            _tc.TrackEvent("Function is Completed Rithwik");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{   "version": "2.0",   "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Then in Portal:

[image]

[image]

Try to follow the above steps to get telemetry client traces in portal and you will get required results as I have got.

**Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: I now created a new project, added packages Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights 3.0.35, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer 2.21.0 and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService 2.21.0 and the instrumentation key setting in local.settings.json but still get "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient'". Are you sure you havn't added a Startup or added something in program.cs? What it did get to work I will add as an answer.

Comment: Forgot to add, now  added **Program.cs** in my edit to the answer.

Comment: Yes, now it works, but reading the documentation I'm afraid this is for non-http workloads so if an application with AppInsights (e.g. asp.net application) is calling this azure function, then we won't get automatic correlations between this AppInsights instances.

Comment: No this works you just can call azure function using HttpClient() and this will work and your ask is for auzre functions and this answer works for it and if you want to get correlations , open a new question for that

Comment: I tested the proposed solution with two applications calling each other and I couldn't get correlation to work. So I added my own answer, which works properly, but I had to wait 10 hours to accept it.