# Custom trace dimensions aren't being logged in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get some custom dimensions in the trace logs some of our Azure Functions but I can't seem to get that working.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
public MyFunctionClass(ILogger logger)
{
  _logger = logger;
}

[Function("MyFunction")]
public void ManualTrigger()
{
  using var scope = _logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["Test"] = "test" });
  _logger.LogInformation("Attempting to log some extra dimensions {dim}", "custom dim");
}
```

The above logs an entry into the trace logs, but that entry has only the following custom dimensions:

- Category
- EventName
- HostInstanceId
- InvocationId
- LogLevel
- ProcessId

I'd expect it to also contain (at the very least a variation of):

- Test
- dim

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: In the past, I have always injected the telemetry client to achieve this.  Its not as clean as just using ILogger, but I'm certain it works. [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#how-can-i-track-telemetry-thats-not-automatically-collected)

Answer (score 0):

> Custom trace dimensions aren't being logged in Azure Function

I have reproduced in my environment and you can achieve the above using below approach:

**`Function1.cs:`**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace FunctionApp64
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request Rithwik.");
            var responseMessage = "done";
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**`CustomTelemetryInitializer.cs`**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CustomTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry tel)
    {
        if (tel is ISupportProperties propTelemetry)
        {
            propTelemetry.Properties["test"] = "test1";
            propTelemetry.Properties["dim"] = "dim2";
            
        }
    }
}
```

**`Startup.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp64.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp64
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetryInitializer>();
        }
    }
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=5f23e;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

[image]

**`host.json:`**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`In portal:`**

[image]

[image]

If you want to create custom event follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301031/how-to-get-application-insights-telemetryclient-in-isolated-net-7-azure-functio/76303747#76303747).

Comment: How would one use this to add dynamic data? Ex. a custom dimension to quickly identify the method / class that generated the log entry? In your example the values are pre-fixed in the `CustomTelemetryInitializer`... In my example in the question I'm adding the extra dimensions in the method where the trace is added, whereas you're adding them "early".

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's an open issue on GitHub related to the default logging configuration as well as a simple workaround available [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7452#issuecomment-1440608624).

The workaround involves adding the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights` Nuget package, as well as adding the following `HostBuilder` configuration (code copied from the linked Github page):

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
            {
                // does not work as per https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/423
                // builder.AddApplicationInsights();

                var applicationInsightsConnectionString = context.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationInsightsConnectionString))
                {
                    builder.AddApplicationInsights(configureTelemetryConfiguration =>
                    {
                        configureTelemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = applicationInsightsConnectionString;
                    }, _ => { });
                }
            })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

The above, when used, makes the custom dimensions work as expected, at least the ones added via `BeginScope`.

Unfortunately it appears that logs added using this method get duplicated in the traces and the traces that DO have the extra dimensions lack the parameters typically added otherwise (such as OperationId).